# Passing IConfiguration into a composition root class method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I wanted to separate my service setup into its own class `CompositionRoot` to follow SRP. Upon doing this, I hit an issue where I need to access my `IConfiguration` service to read the connection string from `appsettings.json`.

Here is the `CompositionRoot` class:

```
public static class CompositionRoot
{
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = null; // I need to access IConfiguration here
        var connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings.production");
        services.AddSingleton<IDbConnection>(provider => new MySqlConnection(connectionString));
    }
}
```

I created a `StartupHelpers` static class, it basically sets up the hosting, configuration, and serilog (the setup process). Here is that class, and it is the class I use to call `CompositionRoot`'s method.

```
public static class StartupHelpers
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder BuildConfig()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        return builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }

    public static IHost BuildHost()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(CompositionRoot.ConfigureServices)
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();
    }

    public static void SetupSerilog(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

How can I access `IConfiguration` (which I get from `BuildConfig`) in the `CompositionRoot` class?

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```
internal static class Program
{
    internal static void Main()
    {
        var configBuilder = StartupHelpers.BuildConfig();

        StartupHelpers.SetupSerilog(configBuilder.Build());

        var host = StartupHelpers.BuildHost();

        host.Services.GetService<IGreetingService>()?.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET Core already handles this, either through the `Startup` class in ASP.NET Core projects or the [HostBuilderContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) parameter to [ConfigureServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostBuilder_ConfigureServices_System_Action_Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_HostBuilderContext_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection__)

Comment: .NET Core's middleware was built with SRP, inversion of control etc in mind. You need to understand how it works before deciding whether it needs further modularization. It's already possible to use separate methods for each responsibility, there's no reason to add new classes. Services and libraries can create extension methods similar to those used by .NET Core (eg AddXYZ, UseXYZ) to add their own configuration and services (eg AddSerilog or UseSerilog)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't want to use separate methods, I felt like having service setup in a different class would isolate that logic so that I would only have to focus on that. I have my reasons is all I'm saying.

Comment: That's done by using separate methods. That's what you also do. You can put them in separate classes if you want, but .NET Core cares about the methods. If you use extension methods, it's even easier to use. You'll have to understand the reasons something is designed the way it is. Using multiple single-method classes does *not* improve SRP. It's the wrong granularity

Comment: Check how [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/tree/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore)'s methods are organized. There are two `Extensions` classes, one for configuring applications and one for the WebHost.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: BTW your `ConfigureServices` doesn't accept the context parameter. Which .NET Core version are you using? 2.1?

Comment: D you mean `HostBuilderContext` ? I think its optional, which at the time of writing it I didn't think I needed it. I'm using NET CORE 3.1

Comment: That class includes a `Configuration` property

Comment: Thank you! Check the accepted answer, I'm certain they are talking about the same thing as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your `IConfiguration` service from the `HostBuilderContext` (which is an argument of the `ConfigureServices` call, which you can pass into the CompositionRoot method.

See here,

```
public static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext host, IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfiguration configuration = host.Configuration;
}
```

Your full method would look something like this,

```
public static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext host, IServiceCollection services)
{
    var configuration = host.Configuration;
    var connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings.production");
    
    services.AddSingleton<IDbConnection>(provider => new MySqlConnection(connectionString));
}
```